# How do I write a java background program that will keep track of my mouse clicks?

Tags: java, background, mouseevent

I am not even sure if it is possible for a java program to register mouse clicks outside of a java component.

What I want to do is run a program (specifically java) that will continuously run and count how many times a user right-clicks until I manually end the process.

Is this possible in java? Is this possible in another language?

Comment: https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook JNativeHook will do exactly what you want. It allows you to listen to all keyboard and mouse events, not just the ones directed at a Java component. I used it to move the mouse a bit after a while of inactivity to prevent Windows from locking.